# Maintaining a "session" with ajax and .net services?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

We have a public facing webserver hosted on a local domain.  I'm trying to authenticate to a .net web service using domain credentials.  I've tried quite a few variants without any success.

The guy that wrote the webservice has now provided `init.aspx`. If I first do a `GET` to that URL, I am prompted to login and get a success.  However, when I do a subsequent post to `http://website.net/cms/api/content/SetContentSectionById` I still get `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Is there a way to pass the "session" or login information back to the server in the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate unique `access token` or `u_id` on server side and sent it back to ajax when login credential works.

Then after successful authentication you can use `Ajax Header` as `Authorization` to validate the logged in user like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://website.net/cms/api/content/SetContentSectionById",
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', access_token); 
  },
  success: function(data, status) {
    return console.log("The returned data", data);
  }
});
```

Comment: We were already sort of on this track, but we are just sending the token as part of the data.  Is this inadvisable?  Also, we discovered that in the .net web api session handling is apparently off by default?

Comment: Also, he is sending the actual session GUID, is this okay?

Comment: Oh yes, then you can use that GUID in authorization or you need to ask to server guy how he is handling the authorization on server? Like if he is using the post method then you can send it in `data : {GUID: GUID}`